# Most user-friendly way to handle an object not found error?

Tags: http, user-interface, http-status-code-404

What do you suppose is the nicest way to handle an "object not found" error?

For example, [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43497835977234732) throws a 404 page not found. But really, I'm pretty sure it *did* find a page, it just didn't find a user with that id in the database. Would it be nicer to return a 404 status code, but use a custom error page saying the object wasn't found?

Is it possibly to return a sub-error code? ASP.NET has errors like `404.1`, but in terms of the actual HTTP status code, does it differ?

Answer (score 1):

Custom error pages are a de-facto standard on serious sites. That said, there are myriads of error conditions for each of the dynamic pages - the user profile page can be missing an ID; answer a question page can be missing a question id; and so on.

It feels wasteful to try to create a custom error page that's designed specifically for each of these scenarios. Basically, you'd need one error page per a page of functionality.

What I do in my applications is send the user to a general-purpose error page, and output a custom message on that page that depends on the error condition.

Comment: Well, I wasn't thinking of doing up a different page for every object type... I'd use some logic to say "User not found", "Question not found", whatever. Every "object" or "model" already has a name.